# Projection operators in a problem about the Hubbard model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, operators, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I am attending a course in Statistical Field theory. So far, we have covered little more than field operators and second quantization. Exercise series are used to introduce topics that we do not discuss in the theoretical classes.
In one of the exercise series of my course, we discuss the Hubbard model. After proving that the Hamiltonian of this model is

[image]

they say that, in order to study the case $U>>t$, we shall introduce projection operators $P_1,P_2$ that project on the subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ of a Hilbert space $H$". They ask me to derive "the effective Hamiltonian $P_1H_{eff}P_1$ that acts on $H_1$" considering that $\vert\Psi_1\rangle = P_1\vert\Psi\rangle$ obeys the Schrodinger equation

$$
            P_1H_{eff}P_1\vert\Psi_1\rangle=E\vert\Psi_1\rangle
$$

*My first question*: how can such an operator $P_1$ make sense? I would think that it was a map $P_1:H\rightarrow H_1$, but that does not make sense because in the Schrodinger equation above we're acting $P_1$ on $\vert\Psi_1\rangle$, an element of $H_1$. To me, it would make sense that our "effective Hamiltonian on $H_1$" was $P_1H_{eff}P_1^{-1}$, where $H_{eff}:H\rightarrow H$. But this is not what they do.

Also, they ask to show that, to second order in $H_c$, this gives

[image]

But they never say what $H_c$ is, and also I don't know what they mean by $\frac{1}{E-P_2HP_2}$ (a fraction with operators).

Comment: Who is "them"?  Are you being followed?

Comment: Other than that, that looks like degenerate 2nd order perturbation theory with low-energy space $P_1$ and high-energy space $P_2$.

Comment: Side comment: Are you sure projection operators have inverses?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Oh, they don't (clearly not injective, I would say)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Alright. Well where can I learn about this? I still don't know how it makes sense, exactly by the reasons I've presented above.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch And yes, I am being followed, and "they" keep asking me questions about physics. I should go to the police

Comment: @Soap In order to get a good answer, it would be good if you could edit your question to give some more details & context.  (Where is this from?  What are the specifications on all the H's and P's?)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Alright, I tried to contextualize the question. If it is not enough, please tell me.

Comment: Better. But what is H1 and H2? And you should ask *them* what $H_c$ is!  The inverse is just the matrix inverse.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch All I know about $H_1$ and $H_2$ is what I've written: "$H$ is a Hilbert space consisting of two subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$". I believe that the question is too unclear.

Comment: I think the question does not makes sense as such -- which is not your fault, but you should ask those who posed the problem for clarification.  This is not a guessing board.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Agreed. I thought it did not make sense *for me* because of my ignorance on the subject (the Hubbard model), that's why I posted the question.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the Hubbard model.  It is basically about deriving a formula for degenerate 2nd order perturbation theory.  Nevertheless, it is underspecified.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but a brief derivation of such a formula is found in Appendix 1 (pg 5) of https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0483.